# How can I prevent clicking iAd from changing my view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, iad

I have an app that displays buttons, the buttons move around the screen upon being touched. The problem I am having is that you can move the buttons around, however if you click on the iAd advertisement after you move the buttons, the buttons return to their original positions. How can I stop this?

Note: I was having the same problem for a while whenever I did a full screen rotation (only landscape supported). Upon rotation the buttons would return to their original positions. I fixed that problem by changing the segue from modal to push. Not sure if this helps but thought I would mention it.

EDIT: I have been trying to use the ViewWillAppear method to correct the layout, however it is not getting called after closing out of the iAd.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it would matter, but just for reference, are you using storyboard or code to place the buttons initially?

Comment: initially placing buttons on storyboard